# Min, Max are slow on TimeObjects

Tags: bugs, date-and-time

fixed in **10.1** (windows)

---

There's something wrong with how `Min` and `Max` are implemented for `TimeObject`:

```
times = {TimeObject[List[0, 14, 55.99`]], TimeObject[List[0, 14, 57.8`]], 
   TimeObject[List[0, 14, 59.09`]], TimeObject[List[0, 14, 59.11`]], 
   TimeObject[List[0, 14, 59.12`]], TimeObject[List[0, 14, 59.14`]], 
   TimeObject[List[0, 14, 59.4`]], TimeObject[List[0, 14, 59.44`]], 
   TimeObject[List[0, 14, 59.45`]], TimeObject[List[0, 14, 59.47`]], 
   TimeObject[List[0, 15, 0.39`]], TimeObject[List[0, 15, 3.27`]], 
   TimeObject[List[0, 15, 5.44`]], TimeObject[List[0, 15, 8.45`]], 
   TimeObject[List[0, 15, 9.34`]], TimeObject[List[0, 15, 12.65`]], 
   TimeObject[List[0, 15, 19.96`]], TimeObject[List[0, 15, 20.82`]]};
```

based on timing:

```
Table[k -> (Take[times, k] // Min // Timing // First), {k, 15}]
```

> {1 -> 0.000021, 2 -> 0.000643, 3 -> 0.000955, 4 -> 0.001439,   5 ->
>   0.002542, 6 -> 0.004146, 7 -> 0.008497, 8 -> 0.019078,   9 -> 0.042076, 10 -> 0.097678, 11 -> 0.227000, 12 -> 0.540869,   13 -> 1.331936, 14 -> 3.248148, 15 -> 8.268877}

Similar numbers for `Max`. Have not tested other functions. This is on a 3.2Ghz Mac. Can anyone else replicate?

Comment: I can confirm the problem in 10.0.2 under Windows.

Comment: Confirmed in MacOS Yosemite, using V10.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed in **10.1**

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code

```
times = {TimeObject[List[0, 14, 55.99`]], 
   TimeObject[List[0, 14, 57.8`]], TimeObject[List[0, 14, 59.09`]], 
   TimeObject[List[0, 14, 59.11`]], TimeObject[List[0, 14, 59.12`]], 
   TimeObject[List[0, 14, 59.14`]], TimeObject[List[0, 14, 59.4`]], 
   TimeObject[List[0, 14, 59.44`]], TimeObject[List[0, 14, 59.45`]], 
   TimeObject[List[0, 14, 59.47`]], TimeObject[List[0, 15, 0.39`]], 
   TimeObject[List[0, 15, 3.27`]], TimeObject[List[0, 15, 5.44`]], 
   TimeObject[List[0, 15, 8.45`]], TimeObject[List[0, 15, 9.34`]], 
   TimeObject[List[0, 15, 12.65`]], TimeObject[List[0, 15, 19.96`]],
    TimeObject[List[0, 15, 20.82`]]};
 Table[k -> (Take[times, k] // Min // Timing // First), {k, 15}]
```

Answer (score 11):

I can confirm the problem in 10.0.2 under Windows.  I think it can only be a bug.

One can at least work around the problem in this example using [`MinimalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinimalBy.html) and [`MaximalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy.html):

```
times2 = RandomSample[times];  (* start with a random order *)

MinimalBy[times2, Identity, 1] // Timing
```

> ```
> {0., {TimeObject[{0, 14, 55.99}]}}
> ```

```
MaximalBy[times2, Identity, 1] // Timing
```

> ```
> {0., {TimeObject[{0, 15, 20.82}]}}
> ```

Answer (score 10):

Confirmed in 10.0.2.0 Windows x64.

`Min` takes exponential time with respect to the number `x` of `TimeObject`s to analyze:

Using `Fit[timings, {1, x, Exp[x]}, x]` on my results here, I get the following equation for the time required:

```
-0.0644554 + 2.89365*10^-6 E^x + 0.0157914 x
```

so, finding the minimum of 20 `TimeObject`s would level in somewhere around 1400 s.

**The current situation with `Min` in graphical form:**

[image: Min for 1 to 15 TimeObjects]

Please report this bug to Wolfram and in the meantime go with Mr. Wizard's workaround or use a construct like

```
times[[Ordering[times, 1]]]
```

which is faster than `MinimalBy` for larger `TimeObject`-lists:

```
tos=RandomSample@NestList[#+QT[RandomReal[30.],"Seconds"]&,TimeObject[],10^4];
First/@{AbsoluteTiming@tos[[Ordering[tos,1]]],AbsoluteTiming@MinimalBy[tos,Identity,1]}
(* {0.001001, 0.016008} *)
```

Comment: +1, and I've filed w/ WRI support. Let me ask about the mothod, a polynomial can fit any finite number of points even if exponentially growing.

Comment: @alancalvitti: Try it and you will find, that a polynomial tends to oscillate between the measurements. This one is clearly an exponential.

Comment: No, for example, take the timing data in my Q and then interpolate using a spline curve - which afaik are all polynomial, including Bezier:  `Map[Apply[List]] // Interpolation[#, Method -> "Spline"] & // 
 Plot[#[x], {x, 0, 15}] &`

Comment: @alancalvitti: True, but have a look at the extrapolation behavior: My function extrapolates correctly. Yours doesn't. Try interpolating a shortened list of timings and observe, if the remainer of the list is "hit". It does with `Exp[x]`, it does not with your polynomial.

Comment: Right, that's an appropriate test - but note that comparison isn't in your original answer.

Comment: @alancalvitti: Neither in your question. Sorry for having provided more analysis than you even asked for.

Comment: Well, I made no claim to complexity. I thanked your effort (+1). Btw, complexity itself is downtrending in the most recent ACM topics survey.